# App Settings Title

Tags: ios, settings, settings-bundle

How do you remove the "[App] Settings" title from showing in the settings?

[image]

Edit:

Here is the code for my Root.plist file. It seems like the PreferenceSpecifiers key has this title as default, but I can't find a way to get rid of it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>Type</key>
                <string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
                <key>Title</key>
                <string>Version</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Type</key>
                <string>PSTitleValueSpecifier</string>
                <key>Key</key>
                <string>versionDisplay</string>
                <key>DefaultValue</key>
                <string>20</string>
                <key>Title</key>
                <string>Version</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Type</key>
                <string>PSTitleValueSpecifier</string>
                <key>Title</key>
                <string>Date Built</string>
                <key>Key</key>
                <string>dateBuild</string>
                <key>DefaultValue</key>
                <string>1</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>StringsTable</key>
        <string>Root</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Locate `Settings.bundle` in project navigator.
2. Look for `Root.plist`. This is the file that describes what's gonna appear in settings.
3. Find a row with `"Queue settings"` string and modify it.

Comment: Edited my post to show my Root.plist code. Unfortunately it isn't a title I am explicitly adding.